# Create custom FAQ module in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, module, custom

I want to create custom FAQ module in magento 2.3.2. with no customer involvement.
in backend admin will add questions and ans. and in frontend, it should display on product details page next to descriptions tab https://prnt.sc/tfa9rm
How should i start with this. Please help.

Comment: You can try this plugin https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-faqs-extensions

Comment: You can check this out to understand the flow of Module and then you can write your own https://github.com/TheFrankman/magento2-faq

Comment: @PushpendraSingh installed this extension. but where it is visible on froentend? what is the url to fetch faq?

Comment: https://www.websites.com/faqs.html or you can find URL on the footer as per module guide which mentioned on same link

Comment: @PushpendraSingh have you used this extension?

Comment: Yes,  I have used it. https://prnt.sc/tfbjbz

Comment: @PushpendraSingh I am not getting expand collapse section. as shown in the doc

Comment: No, it's working on my website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110451/discussion-between-steven-harris-and-pushpendra-singh).

Comment: see this [magento 2 faq](https://www.mageants.com/faq-extension-for-magento-2.html) module and test the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat please use this plugin for your requirement  You can try this plugin **https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-faqs-extensions**